# Не могу сделать отправку в Github из VS Code

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

При попытке отправить изменения в клонированный репозиторий выдает ошибку в VS code "У вас нет разрешений на отправку в GitHub. Вы хотите создать вилку и выполнить отправку в нее?"
Почему я не могу отправить изменения? Что мне делать?

Comment: А у Вас есть такое разрешение? Это Ваш репозиторий или чужой?

Comment: мой, создал его на своем аккаунте на гитхабе своем

Comment: Наверно, Вы клонировали через http, а также не добавили ssh ключи

Comment: я и через http и через ssh пробовал клонировать, все равно vs code говорит что мне нельзя пушить изменения в репозиторий

Comment: тогда показывайте точное сообщение и будем разбираться

Comment: Такое сообщение выдает когда пытаюсь запушить: **"You don't have permissions to push to 'repository' on GitHub. Would you like to create a fork and push to it instead?"**

Comment: проверьте по списку https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17857283/permission-denied-error-on-github-push

Comment: действительно помогло решение оттуда, удалил все данные учетной записи github из windows и все теперь пушится